# Fallback.AsyncFallbackEngine Exception

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception, fallback, polly

I have an application in .NET Framework 4.8 (WCF) that makes http calls, also using Polly for retries and fallback management, but sometimes a `System.NullReferenceException` is raised, but I can't figure out where be the problem. This is the code:

```
private static async Task<bool> CallApi<TRequest>(TRequest request, string requestUri, Func<string, StringContent, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> func)
{
    var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

    var fallBackPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>.Handle<Exception>()
        .FallbackAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther)
        {
            Content = new StringContent($"Exception has occurred in migration call. RequestUri: {requestUri}")
        }, 
        result => 
        {
            LogEventService.Logger.Error(result.Exception, "An unhandled exception occurred while retrying calling");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

    var waitAndRetryPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(res => res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError).
        WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryAttempts => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

    var response = await fallBackPolicy
        .WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy)
        .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            using (var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {
                content.Headers.Add("X-Correlation-ID", HttpContext.Current.Session[RequestId].ToString());

                return await func(requestUri, content);
            }
        });
    
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return true;

    await LogMessage(LogLevel.Error, response, requestUri);
    
    return false;
}
```

and this is the StackTrace

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object.
> at
> UserMigrationService.<>c__DisplayClass22_0'1.<b__3>d.MoveNext()
> in
> ...\Services\UserMigrationService.cs:line 474
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

> at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at
> Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.d__0'1.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Polly.AsyncPolicy'1.d__13.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at
> Polly.Wrap.AsyncPolicyWrapEngine.<>c__DisplayClass0_0'1.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    > at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Polly.Fallback.AsyncFallbackEngine.d__0'1.MoveNext()

Can you help me find where the wrong part is? How can I better understand why this exception is thrown?
Thank you all

Comment: Could you please tell us which line is the 474th?

Comment: Without knowing which line is throwing the exception, my guess is that `HttpContext.Current` is `null` sometimes.

Comment: The line 474th is: `content.Headers.Add("X-Correlation-ID", HttpContext.Current.Session[RequestId].ToString());`
How can HttpContext be null in an HTTP context?

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out the NRE is thrown at this line:

```
ontent.Headers.Add("X-Correlation-ID", HttpContext.Current.Session[RequestId].ToString());
```

Which indicates that `HttpContext.Current` might be `null`. The `ExecuteAsync` receives a delegate which might not be run on same thread as the rest of the code of your `CallApi` method.

That's why the `HttpContext` will not flow into the delegate.

The fix is quite easy: you have to capture the `RequestId` inside the `CallApi`, not inside the `ExecuteAsync` delegate:

```
var correlationId = HttpContext.Current.Session[RequestId].ToString();
var response = await fallBackPolicy
        .WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy)
        .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            using (var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {
                content.Headers.Add("X-Correlation-ID", correlationId);
                return await func(requestUri, content);
            }
        });
```

I would also recommend to use `Policy.Wrap` ([Reference](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap)) instead of calling the `WrapAsync` method on one of the policies. The following two lines are equivalent:

```
fallBackPolicy.WrapAsync(waitAndRetryPolicy)
Policy.WrapAsync(fallbackPolicy, waitAndRetryPolicy)
```

So, your code could be rewritten like this:

```
var correlationId = HttpContext.Current.Session[RequestId].ToString();
var strategy = Policy.WrapAsync(fallbackPolicy, waitAndRetryPolicy);
var response = await strategy
        .ExecuteAsync(async (ct) =>
        {
            using (var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json))
            {
                content.Headers.Add("X-Correlation-ID", correlationId);
                //TODO: pass the cancellationToken to the func
                return await func(requestUri, content);
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None);
```

I've used an other overload of `ExecuteAsync` where you are receiving a `CancellationToken`. This can be extremely useful whenever you consider to use a [TimeoutPolicy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) as well. In that case you should pass that token to the `func` function.

Comment: You were very clear, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I made the change, but I still haven't deployed to the production environment. I update you

Comment: @pampua84 I don't want to look like impatient, but after 2 weeks I think it is a vaild request from me to ask some update from you :)

Comment: Hello sorry thanks for your interest, however, I confirm that the problem is solved, even for this, I had checked the solution. Thanks again

Comment: @pampua84 Great news :D If my proposed solution had used then could you please mark it as the answer to close this topic. If not then please leave a post where you explain how did you solve the problem. Thanks! Have a great day